# Switch to a mobile view with plain HTML

Tags: html, mobile

I need to switch to a mobile view of a website using plain HTML or javascript... er, anything that doesn't require serverside scripting. Our website is being semi-temporarily hosted via Dropbox. ( http://teammetalcow.com redirects to a HTML file in the public folder.) I need a way so that we can detect the user's type of device then display a mobile or desktop version, appropriately. Having a simple way to tack on a mobile site would be prefferred. Is this even possible? Tons of thanks if you can help.

Comment: You could just make adjustments to your CSS combined with media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) to target certain screen sizes. Do you already have a mobile website built? How were you serving the mobile site before?

Comment: Currently, we are not using CSS nor do we have the website built.

Comment: Is CSS an option? You should consider it using it. Alternatively, you could use Javascript to detect mobile clients and then initially load the alternate mobile site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some library like breakpoint : https://github.com/martinmartinmartin/breakpoint/  or study this javascript : http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

you just need to detect device with javascript, then redirect.

```
// in case of a viewport
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 900) {
// scripts --> redirect
    window.location = "http://www.disney.com"
}

// in case of a screen
if (screen.width < 900) {
// scripts --> redirect
    window.location = "http://www.disney.com"
}
```

Carry on

Comment: user2006167, can you add what you found in your comment so other will follow your way for a better improoved answer ?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

if (screen.width<800) {

window.location="../MobileWebsite/MainPage.html";

}

</script>`

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of different things you can do for this. CSS with media queries is one solution, but a more foolproof way to serve a mobile version of your site is to do actual device detection, and load an alternate version of the site depending on device type.

[Apache Mobile Filter](http://www.apachemobilefilter.org/) provides a really painless way to do this, if you're using the Apache webserver. It handles the device detection for you. Once you're detecting mobile devices somehow, you can either redirect users to a mobile-specific site (served from a separate domain or subdirectory, or something along those lines), or use whatever back-end code that you use for generating your site to alternatively display a mobile version of the site when a mobile device is detected (AMF will set HTTP headers telling you if the request is coming from a mobile device, tablet, etc).

There are other options out there as well, but these are probably the simplest approaches.